# Reading rpart Input Parameters from a Text Variable

Tags: r, formula, rpart

I'm using `rpart` to make a decision tree. For example:

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis)
```

How do I read in the formula part from a text file and get it in a format that `rpart` likes? I've tried:

```
predictor_variables <- c("Age", "Number", "Start")
rpart_formula <- Kyphosis ~ parse(text=paste(predictor_variables, collapse="+"))
fit <- rpart(rpart_formula, data=kyphosis)
```

but I get an error:

```
 invalid type (expression) for variable 'parse(text = paste(predictor_variables, collapse = "+"))'
```

How can I format `rpart_formula` so that `rpart` sees it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `as.formula`:

```
rpart_formula <- as.formula(
    paste("Kyphosis ~ ", 
          paste(predictor_variables, collapse = " + "), 
          sep = ""
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply passing the formula as a character string:

```
rpart_formula <-paste("Kyphosis ~ ",paste(predictor_variables, collapse="+"))
```

that should be coerced to a formula by `rpart`.

*Edit*

As noted in the comments below, not all functions will do the coercion for you, so you should not rely on this behavior, but in this case `rpart` *most certainly does*.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work - at least in `lm()` function. Try it in `lm()`.

Comment: @TomasT. No. Why would I try it in `lm` when the question was about `rpart`? I will concede that `lm` doesn't do the coercion. But if you try, you'll see that I'm right and that `rpart` does. Go ahead...I'll wait! ;)

Comment: I'm too lazy to install that package :-) OK, you are probably right it works for rpart, but in principle... in the robustness principle... he may try it next time with different package and it won't work... :-)