# Running lagged regressions with lapply and two arguments

Tags: r, formula, regression, lapply

I am running multiple univariate regressions, like in this reproducible example:

```
require(dynlm)
data(USeconomic)
US<-USeconomic
vars<-colnames(US)[-2]
a<-lapply(colnames(US),function(x) dynlm(log(GNP)~get(x),data=US))
```

`a` contains a list of 3 univariate regressions. Assume now I´d like to run the same regressions with 3 lags: `l<-c(0,1,4)` where 0 is of course the case I already got. Is there a way to use the vector `l`directly, like

```
# this did not work for me, I obtain multivariate regressions including all lags at once
lapply(colnames(US),function(x) dynlm(log(GNP)~L(get(x),l),data=US),l=l)
```

After this did not work I tried another approach and added to following vector:

```
lagged_vars <- paste("L(",rep(vars,each=3),",",l,")",sep="")
```

to get:

```
[1] "L(log(M1),0)" "L(log(M1),1)" "L(log(M1),4)" "L(rs,0)"      "L(rs,1)"     
[6] "L(rs,4)"      "L(rl,0)"      "L(rl,1)"      "L(rl,4)"
```

Unfortunately, I can't run it with the new character vector, get() does not help. I can't understand why cause it works with `vars` but not `lagged_vars` which are both character vectors.

Note, that the `L()` syntax comes from the dynlm package. 
Side question: If I just print a the coefficients from the regression result remain labelled get(x) – how can I change that?

An i,j loop could be possible solution but I´d rather use lapply or something out of this family...

EDIT:
`as.formula` does not work together with `L()` from `dynlm`. I get the this error message:

Error in merge.zoo(log(GNP), L(log(M1), 0), retclass = "list", all = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "L"

EDIT:
found an [interesting post bei Achim Zeileis](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/dynlm-question-How-to-predefine-formula-for-call-to-dynlm-formula-call-td885792.html) referring to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `plyr`

```
library(plyr); library(dynlm); library(tseries)

# FUNCTION TO RUN A SINGLE REGRESSION
foo = function(x, l) dynlm(log(GNP) ~ L(get(as.character(x)), l), data = US)

# CREATE PARAMETER GRID
params = expand.grid(x = colnames(US)[-2], l = c(0, 1, 4))

# RUN REGRESSIONS
regressions = mlply(params, foo)
```

Each element of this list contains details on a single regression from which you can extract your desired output

Comment: Eh, one side question: What if need R^2 or AIC ? I´d use summary to get these. Would you use `lapply(regressions,summary)` then?

Comment: Side answer: `getR2 <- function(lm) summary(lm)$r.squared` and then used lapply.

Answer (score 2):

To construct R formula, you must paste it **all** together, not just the predictor side of it. So you need something like:

```
formula <- as.formula(
    paste("log(GNP)~",
        paste("L(",rep(vars,each=3),",",l,")",sep=""),
        sep = ""
    )
)
```

and then run

```
dynlm(formula, data = ...)
```

Comment: Also see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500219/reading-rpart-input-parameters-from-a-text-variable/7500852#7500852)

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I get an error message, because of L() in the formula, but without as formula `L()` does work.

Comment: What do you mean by "without as formula"?

Comment: by without formula I mean, if I just do it directly `L()` is legit: `dynlm(rl~L(rs,1),data=US)`