# passing a string as a data frame column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame called data.df with various columns say col1,col2,col3....col15. The data frame does not have a specific class attribute but any attribute could be potentially used as a class variable. I would like to use an R variable called target which points to the column number to be treated as class as follows :

```
target<-data.df$col3
```

and then use  that field (target) as input to several learners such as PART and J48 (from package RWeka) :

```
part<-PART(target~.,data=data.df,control=Weka_control(M=200,R=FALSE))
j48<-J48(target~.,data=data.df,control=Weka_control(M=200,R=FALSE))
```

The idea is to be able to change 'target' only once at the beginning of my R code.  How can this be done?

Comment: If what you want to do is just be able to call `col3` instead of `data.df$col3` you can do `attach(data.df)`. But then, you should be careful to use `detach()` when you're done with your data. And if you use more than one dataframe at once, it might be confusing and error prone if you have repeated variable names.

Comment: Antoine, i have read that using attach() is not a good practice. Can you provide an example with 'within'. I have read about it but does not make much sense at my current knowledge of R

Comment: Thank you, here is what i did.

Comment: Yes, it is not good practice, but it exists and is fairly safe if you are only using one dataset at a time. For `within` and `with`, the problem is that it is even more wordy than just typing `data$Variablename`. In your case, `within(data.df, target <- col3)` would append a new column called target with the values of your `col3`, so that does not look like what you want to do. I think `target <- with(data.df, col3)` is closer to what you what to achieve, but, again, longer than `data.df$col3`.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work as expected. The whole point of doing this was to be able to run a number of data mining algorithms and being able to use 'target' as opposed to data.df$col3, data.df$col2,etc The problem is that when a data mining algorithm is used, the column been substituted (in this example col3) is still part of the learning data, which leads to 100% prediction accuracy...

Comment: Sounds like you're going to be happier with the feared `target<- eval(parse(paste('data.df$col',x,sep='')))` where x is the numerical value of your column.

Comment: What? You are making no sense here at all. Can you edit your question and give a real concrete example of what you are trying to do, and why its failing. Otherwise we're just flapping around here in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500219/reading-rpart-input-parameters-from-a-text-variable

Answer (score 23):

I sometimes manage to get a lot done by using strings to reference columns. It works like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(numbers=seq(5))
> df
  numbers
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
> df$numbers
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> df[['numbers']]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

You can then have a variable `target` be the name of your desired column as a string. I don't know about RWeka, but many libraries such as ggplot can take string references for columns (e.g. the `aes_string` parameter instead of `aes`).

Answer (score 6):

If you ask about using [references](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html) in R, it is impossible.

However, if you ask about getting a column by name not explicitly given, this is possible with `[` operator, like this:

```
theNameOfColumnIwantToGetSummaryOf<-"col3"
summary(data.df[,theNameOfColumnIwantToGetSummaryOf])
```

...or like that:

```
myIndexOfTheColumnIwantToGetSummaryOf<-3
summary(data.df[,sprintf("col%d",myIndexOfTheColumnIwantToGetSummaryOf)])
```

Comment: What about multiple columns? I'm aware one can do what you've done with `df[,colName]`, but how might one mix/match nums and names. Example: `df[, c(1,2,4)]` where col 4 has name "colName". How might one do `df[, c(1,2,"colName")]` ? This would be helpful in a loop I'm trying to write.

Comment: @Hendy You can't mix names and numbers; yet you can bind the results of two subscripts (`cbind(df[,c(1,2)],df[,c("colName")])`) or convert names to numbers with `match` (like `match(c("colName","colName2"),names(df))` and mix the result with numerical indices.

Comment: @Hendy Anyway, I have a strange feeling that you are trying too hard doing what you want this way; why won't you ask a Q about the whole loop?